# startsWith() with regex

Tags: r, stringr

I would like to recognise whether string starts with any possible letter, alternatively does not start with `'#'`.

To do so I tried:

```
example <- 'FN647863.1'  
startsWith(example, '[:alpha:]')
```

I expected to get `TRUE`, but unfortunately, I got `FALSE` instead.

Comment: `startsWith()` was not intended to use regex with. Any reason you are opposed to using the `^` character to indicate the beggining of a string in regex? I.e., `grepl("^YOUR_REGEX", example)`. As-is, it is searching for strings that literally start with `"[:alpha:]"`

Comment: Thank you @Andrew! That works perfectly for me when trying ````grepl("^[[:alpha:]]", example)````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Andrew mentioned `startsWith()` was not intended to use regex with.

Then the working solution is:

```
grepl("^[[:alpha:]]", example)
```

Answer (score 1):

`stringr` is also nice for this:

```
stringr::str_detect(example, "^[:alpha:]")
```

or use `"^\\w"` for any word.